# Problema con las rutas que incluyo en el index de mi API REST

Tags: api, rest

Hola estoy desarrollando una `API` con  `slim framework 3` que conecta a una `base de datos` local.
El problema es el siguiente dentro de mi `index.php` yo le paso las `rutas` donde se encuentran las consultas a la base de datos. El problema esta en que no puedo incluir mas de una `ruta`. Por ej si yo paso la ruta `require '../app/route/usuario.php';` y `require '../app/route/persona.php';`, cuando me voy al navegador si quiero ver los usuarios me devuelve el tipico `page no found` y si quiero ver las personas me devuelve los elementos de la tabla persona. Si yo elimino la segunda `ruta` de mi `index`, y pruebo ver los `usuarios` nuevamente en el navegador me los muestra sin problema.

index.php

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../app/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
require '../app/route/usuario.php';
require '../app/route/persona.php';

$app->run();
```

usuario.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->group('/usuario/', function () {

$this-> get('', function(Request $request, Response $response){

$sql = "select * from usuario";

try{
    $db = new db();

    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $usuario = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($usuario);

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
}    
});
```

persona.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->group('/persona/', function () {

$this-> get('', function(Request $request, Response $response){

$sql = "select * from persona";

try{
    $db = new db();

    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $persona = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($persona);

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
}
});
```

Comment: @Mariano perdon, ahi realice las modificaciones solicitadas.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que estás reiniciando la instancia $app = new \Slim\App; dentro de los archivos usuario.php y persona.php Intenta eliminar esas líneas y obtener la instancia de $app mediante la función require llamando al archivo index.php

Comment: Muchas Gracias problema resuelto.

Comment: Resolvi el problema reemplazando la línea `$usuario = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` por `$stmt-> bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);`